# Adding values of two lists and getting sum as zero

Tags: python

I am trying to add values of two lists and appending the result in third list. But receiving null values as output. I am sharing my code .

```
New1
New2
New3 = []
for i,j in range(len(New1), len(New2)):
    Sum = (New1[i] + New2[j])
    New3.append(Sum)
print(New3)
print(len(New3))
```

Result I received is`[] 0`

Please if anyone can provide help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your for loop in the following way:

```
for i,j in zip(New1, New2):
    Sum = i + j
    ...
```

Edit: as Yevhen pointed out, the i and j were the same values, so I fixed it that it uses actual Num1 and Num2 values.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych that's true
thanks for pointing out

Comment: By using this, I am not getting sum of values of list but it is adding values in single list. E.g. list1 = [1,2,3] list2 = [4,5,6] it is giving result as list3 = [1,2,3,4,5,6] but the answer must be list3 = [5,7,9]

Comment: @user1639130 try now

Answer (score 0):

Just zip the two arrays and add the sum to the new array:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [10,20,30]
c = []

for i,j in zip(a,b):
    c.append(i+j)

print(c)
```

Returns:

```
[11, 22, 33]
```

Comment: By using this, I am not getting sum of values of list but it is adding values in single list. E.g. list1 = [1,2,3] list2 = [4,5,6] it is giving result as list3 = [1,2,3,4,5,6] but the answer must be list3 = [5,7,9]

Comment: Have you copied the code properly? I've tried  the code again with the expected result!